# Result for a particular user

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to diplay a result for a particular user along with a list of all items and the information whether the user ordered that item or not.

I have 3 tables, accounts (t1), items (t2), and t3 that contains item_id, item_name, stat, shipped.

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  shipped tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Last time I got help with the JOINs, but it does not show all the item_id and item_name for a partical user. It should be like this https://pastebin.com/XNCAEGtp .

```
SELECT 
    t2.item_id,
    t2.item_name,
    t3.stat,
    t3.shipped
    t1.user_name,
FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.item_id
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t3.user_id = t1.userid
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit confusing that the pastebin link does not show a user but your query has no  where clause to 'display a result for a particular user'

Comment: i need the user_id for my php script. all of them will be displayed in a <table> tag except the user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all items for the given user (the CROSS JOIN between t1 and t2), and the order `stat` and `shipped` columns will be null where not ordered:

```
SELECT 
    i.id AS item_id,
    i.item_name,
    IFNULL(o.stat, 'n/a') AS stat,
    IFNULL(o.shipped, 'n/a') AS shipped,
    a.user_name
FROM accounts a
CROSS JOIN items i
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON a.id = o.user_id
    AND i.id = o.item_id
WHERE a.id = ?
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TJ3p9K1A)

Comment: Sorry, I saved some changes before I realised you had accepted it. Hope it still meets your needs.